# how to write TableForm expression into file?

Tags: export, output-formatting, files-and-directories

Now I have a list stored in `data` as follows

```
data = {{"Ca", 1, 1, 1}, {"Ca", 2, 2, 2}, {"Ca", 3, 3, 3}}
```

the `TableForm` of `data` is of course as follows:

```
Ca  1   1   1
Ca  2   2   2
Ca  3   3   3
```

But how to write this `TableForm` of `data` into a file?

I tried code like

```
OutputForm[TableForm[data]]>>"test"
```

But the result is

```
Ca   1   1   1

Ca   2   2   2

Ca   3   3   3
```

**Why there are blank lines????** How to prevent the emergence of these blank lines when write TableForm expression into a file?

Comment: Why don't you simply use Export["test", data, "Table"]

Comment: @Algohi Thank you! I think Lou's answer which is to control `TableSpacing` is more flexible, for example in `OpenWrite` and `Write` cases? But there is a problem, the accuracy of the number that `OutputForm` gives is not enough sometimes, do you know other method to solve this?

Comment: @matheorem What do you mean it is "not enough sometimes"?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you, Mr. Wizard. I mean if `data = {{"Ca", 1.123456789, 1.98765432}}`, then `OutputForm[TableForm[data, TableSpacing -> {0, 3}]] >> "test"` will give `Ca   1.12346   1.98765`, you can see the accuracy is downgrade. But Lou gives addtional answer that suggest using `SetAccuracy`, it works well. What do you think of Lou's method?

Comment: It looks fine to me, and since that addition addresses your concern I'd say it earns Acceptance.  I haven't benchmarked that code however and one lingering concern would be that it might not perform as well as a manual approach using `WriteString`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard what does `one lingering concern would be that it might not perform as well as a manual approach using WriteString` mean?

Comment: I mean only that a different approach might be faster (or slower) but I haven't bothered to implement it to find out.  Unless you run into a performance problem I don't intend to spend time to do so.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it is advisable to use the `Export` command:

```
Export["test", data, "Table"]
```

Leads to:

[image]

Alternative one can use `TableSpacing` i.e. manipulate space between rows or columns,

```
OutputForm[TableForm[data, TableSpacing -> {0, 0}]] >> "test"
```

this leads to;

[image]

**Edit**

One can control Accuracy by:

```
data1 = SetAccuracy[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 4}], 4]
```

> {{-0.630, -0.379, -0.717, -0.968}, {-0.497, -0.609, 
>     0.461, -0.121}, {-0.463, -0.303, -0.574, 0.527}}

```
OutputForm[TableForm[data1, TableSpacing -> {0, 2}]] >> "uups"
```

yields to:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful solution! Thank you!

Comment: As I metioned in the reply to Algohi. I just found that the accuracy of numbers that `OutputForm` gives is much lower than `Export` gives. But `Export` seems not univeral in file operation like `OpenWrite` and `Write`, so is there a better solution?

Comment: This can be seen if you try real number like 0.1234567896 instead of integer.