# Sorting out atom types in an XYZ file

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, sorting, chemistry

I am trying to rewrite the output of "VertexCoordinates" such that instead of a hybrid list of atoms and coordinates that result from using the following input program, I want all coordinates of the SAME atom (e.g. H atoms) listed first, preceded by the total number of H atoms, and then followed by the total number of C atoms before a list of all coordinates of C atoms and so on. This will be used as input to an ELK file.

```
Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", {{"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}]
ExportString[%, {"XYZ", {"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}]
```

Expected output is as follows (pls note that this is not exactly a molecule due to compression)

```
atoms
 3 : nspecies
 'H.in' : spfname
 5 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
 0.34100000 0.52900000 0.10100000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.65900000 0.47100000 0.60100000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.15900000 0.02900000 0.60100000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.84100000 0.97100000 0.10100000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.34700000 0.34800000 0.99500000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  'C.in' : spfname
 6 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
 0.48630000 0.11560000 0.04910000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.51370000 0.88440000 0.54910000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.01370000 0.61560000 0.54910000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.98630000 0.38440000 0.04910000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.44602000 0.30860000 0.10260000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.55398000 0.69140000 0.60260000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 'N.in' : spfname
 4 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
 0.37630000 0.42680000 0.04850000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.62370000 0.57320000 0.54850000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.12370000 0.92680000 0.54850000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 0.87630000 0.07320000 0.04850000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Comment: Just a personal style recommendation: Writing out things like "please" in full somehow makes questions seem more professional (and sometimes dampens codez rqst allergic reflexes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with the specific output format you need but I think I can show you how to proceed.

```
dat = Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", {{"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}];

dat2 = {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[dat\[Transpose], First];

dat3 = {#, Length@#2, #2} & @@@ dat2;
```

`dat3` has this format:

```
dat3 // TableForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{H} & 10 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -338.041 & -112.724 & 57.3304 \\
>  254.97 & 297.35 & 62.2959 \\
>  -248.077 & -272.695 & 48.8263 \\
>  -300.89 & -190.253 & -104.98 \\
>  291.761 & -184.815 & -78.5787 \\
>  237.879 & -112.119 & -237.437 \\
>  171.899 & -274.899 & -184.392 \\
>  -16.8703 & 404.366 & 93.0109 \\
>  35.3532 & 329.791 & 251.777 \\
>  -120.745 & 275.376 & 172.03 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \text{N} & 4 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  96.683 & -107.374 & -81.9823 \\
>  -137.517 & -102.122 & -5.70552 \\
>  56.0263 & 208.391 & 82.5159 \\
>  228.613 & 99.6844 & -24.403 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \text{C} & 8 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  5.67293 & 85.2719 & 39.2316 \\
>  -126.15 & 25.9071 & 52.3414 \\
>  -30.6834 & -168.363 & -71.6934 \\
>  113.942 & 18.7412 & -27.009 \\
>  -263.281 & -173.04 & -0.60953 \\
>  205.274 & -173.609 & -149.313 \\
>  -15.1845 & 309.7 & 153.483 \\
>  189.341 & 211.812 & 41.9319 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \text{O} & 2 & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -49.268 & -281.806 & -120.947 \\
>  -223.013 & 79.8862 & 108.997 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

If you give a manually created example of the exact output that you need I can try to give code for that as well.

---

I believe this produces the formatting that you want.  It's not particularly clean but it should work.

```
(* helper function using method from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55904/ *)
tableToString = 
  ToString @ PaddedForm[#, {6, 6}] & @ TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {0, 1}] &;

(* method from above *)
group =
  {#, Length@#2, #2} & @@ {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[#\[Transpose], First] &;

format[dat_] :=
  "" <> Riffle[#, "\n"] & @ Join[{"atoms", ToString@Length@dat <> " : nspecies"}, ##] & @@
   Cases[dat, {name_, count_, tab_?MatrixQ} :>
     {"'" <> name <> ".in' : spfname", ToString@count <> " : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below",
       tableToString[tab/100]}]
```

Test:

```
Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", {{"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}] // group // format
```

> ```
> atoms
> 4 : nspecies
> 'H.in' : spfname
> 10 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
> -3.380410 -1.127240  0.573304
>  2.549700  2.973500  0.622959
> -2.480770 -2.726950  0.488263
> -3.008900 -1.902530 -1.049800
>  2.917610 -1.848150 -0.785787
>  2.378790 -1.121190 -2.374370
>  1.718990 -2.748990 -1.843920
> -0.168703  4.043660  0.930109
>  0.353532  3.297910  2.517770
> -1.207450  2.753760  1.720300
> 'N.in' : spfname
> 4 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
>  0.966830 -1.073740 -0.819823
> -1.375170 -1.021220 -0.057055
>  0.560263  2.083910  0.825159
>  2.286130  0.996844 -0.244030
> 'C.in' : spfname
> 8 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
>  0.056729  0.852719  0.392316
> -1.261500  0.259071  0.523414
> -0.306834 -1.683630 -0.716934
>  1.139420  0.187412 -0.270090
> -2.632810 -1.730400 -0.006095
>  2.052740 -1.736090 -1.493130
> -0.151845  3.097000  1.534830
>  1.893410  2.118120  0.419319
> 'O.in' : spfname
> 2 : natoms; atposl, bfcmt below
> -0.492680 -2.818060 -1.209470
> -2.230130  0.798862  1.089970
> ```

The output is a String.  You can export it with e.g. `Export["file.txt", string, "Text"]`.

Comment: There appears to be a magnification in  coordinates...

Comment: @thils Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Please see new edits

Comment: @thils The coordinates shown in my answer are as they are given by `Import` in the first line.  How should they be scaled or translated?

Comment: @Wizard Not a worry, divide by 100 to convert to Angstroms, minor issue. But the main query relates to the expected output explained above.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my attempt at producing the output style that you desire where i have assumed that all co-ordinates should be padded with three zeroes at the end.

```
data = Import[
"ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", {{"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}];
```

Gather co-ordinates of same elements

```
table = Table[
 If[data[[1, #]] == data[[1, i]], Sow[N[data[[2, i]]/100]], 
  Unevaluated[Sequence[]]], {i, 1, Length[data[[1]]]}] & /@ 
 GatherBy[Range@Length[data[[1]]], data[[1]][[#]] &][[All, 1]]
```

Gather all the distinct elements

```
elements = 
data[[1, #]] & /@ 
 GatherBy[Range@Length[data[[1]]], data[[1]][[#]] &][[All, 1]];
 total = Length@table[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@table
```

Format by padding with 3 zeroes and 8 digits after decimal

```
 padtable = 
 Table[NumberForm[PadRight[table[[i, #]], 6, 0], {8, 8}] & /@ 
 Range[Length[table[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[table]}]
```

Finally display the result with required string structure

```
 result = Table[{ToString["'"] <> ToString[elements[[i]]] <> 
    ToString[".in' : spfname"], 
  ToString[total[[i]]] <> ToString[": natoms; atposl, bfcmt below"], 
  padtable[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[table]}]
```

P.S. There seems to be a problem with **NumberForm** when exporting the final result. Maybe someone can provide some help on this.

Comment: I have asked a separate question regarding the issue with **Numberform**. Here's the link 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60225/problem-with-numberform-when-exporting