# Problem with NumberForm when exporting

Tags: export, list-manipulation, data-format

I have a two-part question regarding **NumberForm**

> First question

In my attempt at answering [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60195/sorting-out-atom-types-in-an-xyz-file) i stumbled upon a strange behavior by **NumberForm** when the final result is exported.

Lets say I have a simple Table output as shown below which uses the command **NumberForm**

```
t1 = Table[{i, NumberForm[Range[i], {2, 2}]}, {i, 1, 2}]
```

Now if I export this it works fine

```
   Export["try.dat", t1];
   FilePrint["try.dat"]
  (* 1  {1.00} *)
  (* 2  {1.00, 2.00}*)
```

But if i slightly tweak the Table like this

```
 t2 = Table[{i, NumberForm[Range[i + #], {2, 2}] & /@ Range[2]}, {i, 1, 2}]
```

Now on export **NumberForm** remains unevaluated

```
  Export["try.dat", t2];
  FilePrint["try.dat"]

(* 1    {NumberForm[{1, 2}, {2, 2}], NumberForm[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2}]} *)
(* 2    {NumberForm[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2}], NumberForm[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 2}]} *)
```

So why is this happening?

> Second question

Also while searching I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20385/how-can-i-control-the-number-format-of-exported-data) where the OP asked and answered his own question regarding **NumberForm** but when I run his/her solution it's not giving the expected answer in my machine (*Windows 8 with mma 9*). Below is the code which the OP gave.

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 0.4, 0.01}];
time2 = Table[NumberForm[i, 6], {i, 0, 0.4, 0.01}];
op = Table[time[[i]]^2 + time[[i]], {i, 1, Length@time}];
Export["data.dat", Transpose@{time2, op}, "Table"];
FilePrint["data.dat"];
```

Can someone confirm what they get on running the above piece matches with whats given in that thread. I'm getting some numbers which are not formatted.

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to do with `Export`. if `t2` evaluated correctly, the export would have been fine. And `t2` does evaluate correctly on my system, which is V10 on OS X.

Comment: but isn't t2 giving the expected result. i see no problem in the output of t2

Comment: Re your second question, yes, some numbers on the second column are not formatted as in the linked answer (version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 6-bit). With a small change (`Export["data.dat", Transpose@{time2, NumberForm[#, 6] & /@ op}, "Table"];`  you get the same result as in the linked answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm the issue in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64-bit). A workaround is wrapping `NumberForm` with `OutputForm`:

```
t2b = Table[{i, OutputForm[NumberForm[Range[i + #], {2, 2}]] & /@ Range[2]}, {i, 1, 2}]
Export["tryb.dat", t2b];
FilePrint["tryb.dat" ]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Not sure why that works.  Must be in the fine detail of the evaluation process.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra pair of list brackets in `t2` which you can remove like so:-

```
t2 = Table[{i, Apply[Sequence,
    NumberForm[Range[i + #], {2, 2}] & /@ Range[2]]}, {i, 1, 2}]
```

Then it works like `t1`.

```
Export["try.dat", t2];
FilePrint["try.dat"]

(* 1    {1.00, 2.00}    {1.00, 2.00, 3.00} *)
(* 2    {1.00, 2.00, 3.00}  {1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00} *)
```

Comment: This is fine but whats wrong with an extra bracket from the point of view of Export. I mean why Export fails to write the result given by t2.

Comment: The export format, which appears to be `"Data"`, seems to expect only a two-dimensional grid of data.  So the nested items in the sublists are not being evaluated like the top level items during the `Export` process.

Comment: Chris, if you copy/paste the output of  `t2` (OP's version) into the second argument of `Export` it works ok.

Comment: @kguler - Yes, copy & paste evaluates the `NumberForm` statements.  `FullForm[t2]` shows `NumberForm` unevaluated.  So `Export` does not evaluate like copy & paste.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen But FullForm[t1] also shows NumberForm unevaluated and yet Export works in that case.

Comment: @Hubble07 - `Export` *will* evaluate `NumberForm` but in only the top level terms of a two-dimensional grid of data.  That is, unless `OutputForm` is used, which somehow forces evaluation.  Quite interesting.