# Unexpected results from output with NumberForm and ScientificForm

Tags: list-manipulation, export, output-formatting

I wrote this little function to help me export tables with formatted numbers to files:  (By the way, if you have suggestions on how to make it more efficient and compact, it would be great)

```
Options[exportSimpleFormatTable] = {numberFormat -> NumberForm, 
formArgument -> {2, 1}, fortranOutput -> False}

exportSimpleFormatTable[filename_?StringQ, vectorcolumn__, 
opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{len, list, formfu, formarg, numfun, formattedlist},
list = List@vectorcolumn;
len = Length@list;
list = Thread[list];
numfun = OptionValue[numberFormat];
formarg = OptionValue[formArgument];
formfu = Function[numfun[#, formarg]];
 If[OptionValue[fortranOutput] == True, 
  formfu = Function[ScientificForm[#,
    NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] &)]]];
  formattedlist = MapAt[formfu, list, {All, All}];
  Print[formattedlist];
  Export[filename, formattedlist, "Table"]
]
```

When I use it like this:

```
 zzz = {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5}
 bbb = {0.992, 0.855, 1.411, 1.083, 0.744, 1.292, 1.363, 1.988, 1.111, 
 0.7112, 1.573, 1.1423}
```

Everything works fine:

```
exportSimpleFormatTable["test.dat", zzz, bbb, 2*zzz, 
 fortranOutput -> False]

 (* {{0.4,1.0,0.8},{0.5,0.9,1.0},{0.6,1.4,1.2},{0.7,1.1,1.4},{0.8,0.7,1.6},{0.9,1.3,1.8},{1.0,1.4,2.0},{1.1,2.0,2.2},{1.2,1.1,2.4},{1.3,0.7,2.6},{1.4,1.6,2.8},{1.5,1.1,3.0}} *)

FilePrint["test.dat"]

0.4 1.0 0.8
0.5 0.9 1.0
0.6 1.4 1.2
0.7 1.1 1.4
```

However when I set the fortranOutput option to True, I get:

```
exportSimpleFormatTable["test.dat", zzz, bbb, 2*zzz, fortranOutput -> True]

{{4.e-1,9.92e-1,8.e-1},{5.e-1,8.55e-1,1.e0},{6.e-1,1.411e0,1.2e0},{7.e-1,1.083e0,1.4e0},{8.e-1,7.44e-1,1.6e0},{9.e-1,1.292e0,1.8e0},{1.e0,1.363e0,2.e0},{1.1e0,1.988e0,2.2e0},{1.2e0,1.111e0,2.4e0},{1.3e0,7.112e-1,2.6e0},{1.4e0,1.573e0,2.8e0},{1.5e0,1.1423e0,3.e0}}
```

But `FilePrint` gives me unevaluated things:

```
FilePrint["test.dat"]

ScientificForm[0.4, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )] ScientificForm[0.992, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )]   ScientificForm[0.8, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )]
ScientificForm[0.5, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )] ScientificForm[0.855, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )]   ScientificForm[1., NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] & )]
```

So, there is a difference between the internal `Print` and the `Export`.
However when I use this accepted answer: [Problem with NumberForm when exporting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60225/problem-with-numberform-when-exporting), which suggests wrapping `ScientificForm` with `OutputForm`, 
I get something even weirder:

```
exportSimpleFormatTable[filename_?StringQ, vectorcolumn__, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{len, list, formfu, formarg, numfun, formattedlist},
  list = List@vectorcolumn;
  len = Length@list;
  list = Thread[list];
  numfun = OptionValue[numberFormat];
  formarg = OptionValue[formArgument];
  formfu = Function[numfun[#, formarg]];
  If[OptionValue[fortranOutput] == True, 
   formfu = 
    Function[
     OutputForm@
      ScientificForm[#, 
       NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", 
            If[ToString[#3] == "", 0, #3]}] &)]]];
  formattedlist = MapAt[formfu, list, {All, All}];
  Print[formattedlist];
  Export[filename, formattedlist, "Table"]
  ]


exportSimpleFormatTable["test.dat", zzz, bbb, 2*zzz, 
  fortranOutput -> True]

{{4.e-1,9.92e-1,8.e-1},{5.e-1,8.55e-1,1.e0e0},{6.e-1,1.411e0e0,1.2e0e0},{7.e-1,1.083e0e0,1.4e0e0},{8.e-1,7.44e-1,1.6e0e0},{9.e-1,1.292e0e0,1.8e0e0},{1.e0e0,1.363e0e0,2.e0e0},{1.1e0e0,1.988e0e0,2.2e0e0},{1.2e0e0,1.002e2,2.4e0e0},{1.3e0e0,7.112e-1,2.6e0e0},{1.4e0e0,1.573e0e0,2.8e0e0},{1.5e0e0,1.1423e0e0,3.e0e0}}
```

I get this strange e0e0's which don't happen for e-1 (or other exponents as I have checked)

But the `FilePrint` now works fine (although with that strange error in e0e0):

```
FilePrint["test.dat"]

4.e-1   9.92e-1 8.e-1
5.e-1   8.55e-1 1.e0e0
6.e-1   1.411e0e0   1.2e0e0
7.e-1   1.083e0e0   1.4e0e0
8.e-1   7.44e-1 1.6e0e0
9.e-1   1.292e0e0   1.8e0e0
1.e0e0  1.363e0e0   2.e0e0
1.1e0e0 1.988e0e0   2.2e0e0
1.2e0e0 1.002e2 2.4e0e0
1.3e0e0 7.112e-1    2.6e0e0
1.4e0e0 1.573e0e0   2.8e0e0
1.5e0e0 1.1423e0e0  3.e0e0
```

Does somebody have an idea what is going here?? I tried to use different forms of `Map`, `Thread`, and so on, but nothing works. Also other solutions here on SE don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[#3 == "", "0", #3]}] &)
```

The elements of NumberFormat need to be strings, so the `0` needs to be a `"0"` than it works.

btw `#1`,`#2`,`#3` are of course allready strings so `ToString` on any of these slots is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I oversaw that. Now it works fine and I get the e0 at the end which is what I wanted.